# PFQueryTableViewController as part of a tab controller?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm trying to use PFQueryTableViewController but I can't get to minimise it so it won't take over the entire screen (top to bottom).

My main goal is to place in a tab controller so one of the tabs will display a table - but even after adding a title the table is still under the title and not just below it (first record is hidden...)

Is there a way to manipulate it a bit? All the videos I could find ended up with a full screen table - which is cool to have in 2 minutes but it's not usable at all.

Thanks!

Comment: can send me the code ?

Comment: I used the regular code examples I could find - all show the same result of a table showing all over the screen while I want to have the title's gap (which is normal)

Answer (score 0):

By using:

```
  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if (section == self.objects.count) {
    return 0.0f;
}
return 65.0f;
}
```

I was able to arrange the table layout.